# Accessing Input element through input name in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to access the following code using java script. Can anyone help me please? I'm a beginner to JavaScript.

```
<input type="text" name="username" />
```

I wish to access the element from its name property. An alert box needs to be shown if the length of element value is less than 6.

Comment: try this `document.getElementsByTagName('username')`

Comment: What do you want to with the input. Please be specific if you wish to select element or its value or need to add css.

Comment: I want to access the value of the username and check its length and if it's less than 6 then i hav to alert wd a msg....  That's my objecive!!

Comment: @GSURENDARTHINA: Please consider searching stackoverflow for similar questions. I bet there are plenty of questions here to guide you. I have posted an answer which you can user in any function or form submit.

Comment: Thanks for it!! I'm getting clear gradually!! (y)

Comment: @Girish i believe you meant to type `getElementsByName`

Comment: @Sangram you do not need to add css, you SHOULD add an html id attribute

Answer (score 1):

Use *getElementsByName()* method,

```
document.getElementsByName('username')
```

getElementsByName() returns an array of elements.

Comment: Thanks user!! I have got the output that I wanted!! Thank You so much!!

Answer (score 1):

The getElementsByName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified name

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("username")[0].tagName;
```

Its better you can use id instead of name if it is unique.

```
<input type="text" id="username" />

var x=document.getElementById("username");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `document.getElementById()`, need to specify unique id

```js
var usrtxt = document.getElementById('usrtxt');
alert(usrtxt.name + ": " + usrtxt.value);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="username" id='usrtxt' value='admin' />
```

Try using `document.getElementsByTagName()`

```js
var inputArray = document.getElementsByTagName('input');//gives array
var usrtxt = inputArray[0];//get first element
alert(usrtxt.name + ": " + usrtxt.value);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="username" value='admin' />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to identify particular element using Name then use `getElementsByName` function

**Javascript:**

```
var x = document.getElementsByName('username');
```

If you consider to use the Jquery then please use following code.
**Jquery:**

```
$('[name="username"]');
```

Learn more about [Jquery Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

**Update:**

```
var x = document.getElementsByName('username'); // X is an array here as getElementsByName returns collection i.e. Array
var val = x[0];//get first element
if(val.value.length < 6) // Check if its value greater than 6
  {
   alert('boom !!');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the input is in a form like:

```
<form ...>
  <input name="username">
  ...
</form>
```

and probably you want to validate it when the form is submitted, so in that case you likely have a listener on the form like:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate(this)" ...>
```

and in the validate function:

```
function validate(form) {

  // get input as form.username
  if (form.username.value.length < 6) {
    alert('Username must be 6 or more characters long');

    // Prevent form submission
    return false;
  }
}
```

You may want to be more sophisticated with the UI (your users will appreciate it), but the above shows the basics.